# How to create a dynamically scheduled task?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, cron, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to create an app that simulates opening a tab at a bar. I am running into one issue that I can't seem to figure out - it goes as follows:

1. When someone opens a bar tab, dynamically create a scheduled task that executes code to close the tab after 24 hours.
2. If the tab gets closed before the 24 hours, cancel the scheduled task.

3. If the tab doesn't get closed after 24 hours, execute the code described in step 1 to initiate a payment on the card used to open the tab.

I was initially looking into Firebase Functions, and was thinking about using a setTimeout() callable function, but after doing some research I found that Firebase Function's cannot be invoked for longer than 9 minutes.

**NOTE:** I would like this to be dynamic. Meaning, having it account for a variable amount of users. There could be 100 or 1000 users on the platform, each of them needs the ability to have a unique scheduled task for them (sometimes multiple per user).

Comment: May I offer some minor tips on writing good questions?  Asking for the "best way" is highly subjective unless you define the objective criteria for "best".  Just phrase your question like "how can I create dynamically scheduled tasks".  Also statements like "please let me know what you think the best solution is to tackle this problem" are fluff and can be omitted.  We all understand that you want an answer...because you asked a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Please see the comments for the full solution.*

There are multiple approaches to circumvent the 10 minutes rule (which is prevalent in the serverless code) but here's something that can help you. I suggest separating the task into three:

1. A cloud function that close the tab when called.
2. A schedule function that calls it (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions)
3. A way to start and stop the schedule function.

I am not sure how firebase function work, but I worked with azure functions before and those can be controlled with command line (CLI) or with a sdk for your language of choice. To cancel using the command line, try something like this:

```
firebase functions:delete scheduledFunction
```

from [How to cancel a scheduled firebase function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59116635/how-to-cancel-a-scheduled-firebase-function).

Now what's left is how to figure out how to start the function, and if it's possible to pass in a parameter to schedule it.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the response!

I have a few more questions. When a schedule function is created, am I able to create these dynamically (for multiple users, and pass necessary payment information to these scheduled functions)? 

Also, is there a way to uniquely identify a scheduled task, so that I can remove it specifically if a user closes the tab?

Comment: @Devon I'm not too familiar with cloud functions, but you can uniquely identify them using the name. In azure world there is a unique _instance id_, but I'm not sure if that's available. I recommend against passing payment / user info directly on a scheduled function. You should store that in a database and have the main cloud function take care of that

Comment: Regarding payment information, I'm utilizing Stripe's API so it's securely handled there. I'd merely pass the user's customer ID to the scheduler. I guess what I'm still not quite sure about is let's say User A opens a tab at 8pm and User B opens a tab at 8:30pm - I'm looking to create a dynamically scheduled function for both users to close their tabs exactly 24 hours later (8 & 8:30pm respectively). Will this solution be able to do that for me? I might be missing something here. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Devon Yes, passing only the customer ID to the scheduler is safe. Usually it's a POST request to start it, and you can put that info in the body. What I have in mind is creating one function per user. So you should have a schedule function called something like _scheduleUser1_ with CRON set to `('0 20 * * *')` and a second one _scheduleUser2_ with CRON set to `('30 20 * * *)`. I used https://crontab.guru/#0_8_*_*_* to generate the CRON

Comment: However, if you have a lot of users then, it's going be a lot of functions.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. What if the user base is variable (users being added daily)? I get your solution if the user base is fixed, but if this were to scale how could I account for that? Thanks.

Comment: That's a great question. If there is there a limit to the number of functions you can create on cloud then it's not ideal if the users are increasing. Usually, the serverless functions are stateless, so you are not supposed to save data (userId) to identify them. There are probably ways to go around that but you'll have to do some digging. If not I recommend building and deploying a typical node js server (or a tech of your choice)

Comment: Got it, thank you for all your help. I've been thinking about deploying an Express server that will handle this functionality. OR I've also considered running a CRON job every minute on Firebase Functions that loops through all open tabs in Firestore to check if the time it needs to be closed by is <= current time - in that case, close it. Which option do you think is best?

Comment: Well, it depends how accurate / time sensitive you need the task to be. If the task time accuracy of around a minute is okay, then you can have a scheduled function run every minute to check ALL tabs (or orders) and close those that are expired. I assume those tabs are stored in a database? The model of this tab should include _userId_, _startTime_ and _isActive_. This option is better than deploying your own express server if you can sacrifice a bit of accuracy for easier scalability and much better cost.

Comment: Yeah +/- one minute is totally fine for this project, and yes everything is stored in the database (*userId*, *closeTimestamp*, *status*). I think I'm going to implement that solution. Thank you for all your help!